# What is the difference between postback, autopostback and callback?

Tags: asp.net

can you define autopostback and postback and it's differences  and which web server control support autopostback and postback and also the difference between postback and callback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A postback is initiated by the browser, and reloads the whole page, usually when a control on the page (e.g. a button) is changed.

With some controls (e.g. Checkboxes), you choose if changing the control should result in a postback. This property is called AutoPostback.

A callback is initiated by java script in the page, and can load/update parts of the page, e.g. by manipulating the DOM.

Comment: but we can also uplode and change page while page is postback

Answer (score 10):

- *postback*: the page performs a POST request to itself
- *autopostback*: a postback is performed automatically, for example when the selected value of a dropdown changes
- *callback*: a method which is invoked when a certain event occurs such as clicking on a button. It also could have another meaning that a page performs a request back to the server (such as an AJAX request).

Comment: +1 - but isn't *callback* (i.e. Page.IsCallback) simply used to differentiate a normal postback from an ajax request?

Comment: @M4N, good point, depending on the context it could mean that a page performs a request to the server. I've updated my answer to take this into consideration.

Comment: same thing also happen with postback, while postback happen when user fire any event on browser...i am not satisfied with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Controls that support AutoPostback includes:

- List item
- ListControl
- BulletedList
- CheckBoxList
- DropDownList
- ListBox
- RadioButtonList
- CheckBox
- TextBox

Answer (score 1):

- ***PostBack*** happens when data is send to the server (he page performs a POST request to itself)
- ***IsPostBack*** helps you to identify if postback happen or not
- ***Autopostback*** if this property of control is true helps to you post as soon as data change on the contol or some event occur
- ***callback*** is a special postback, so a round-trip always occurs; however, unlike the classic postback, the script callback doesn't redraw the whole page. ViewState is not updated during a callback, it is for postback.