# difference b/w page refresh and autoPostback

Tags: asp.net

Tell me the all events which is called when an asp.net page is refresh

and difference b/w page refresh and autoPostBack in ASP.NET with respect to the events calling?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581893/what-is-the-difference-between-postback-autopostback-and-callback

Comment: please search the site for your question before posting new questions :)